# How do i check if cell is colored and get their postion in the table with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Currently my table's cell is able to change color on click by changing the class of the cell. What i want to achieve here is, when i click on the book button, how to i check the entire table if one of the cell is colored red and get their coordinates on the table? My table is linked to the database but it is actually a 4x23 table. Heres the codes

HTML + Javascript

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="booking.css">
</head>
<style>

</style>

<body>

    <table id="tblMain">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th >Studio 1</th><th >Studio 2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td>
            <td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td>
            <td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>3</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr><tr><td>8</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr><tr><td>9</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr><tr><td>10</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr><tr><td>11</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr><tr><td>12</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr><tr><td>13</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr><tr><td>14</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr><tr><td>15</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr><tr><td>16</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr><tr><td>17</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr><tr><td>18</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr><tr><td>19</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr><tr><td>20</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr><tr><td>21</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr><tr><td>22</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr><tr><td>23</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td><td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)'>booked</td></tr> 
    </table>
    <button onclick="Bookings()">Book</button>

<script>
function cSwap(cell){  
    if (cell.className == "t")
        cell.className = "t2";
    else if (cell.className == "t2")
        cell.className = "t";
}

function Bookings(){
        var booked = document.getElementsByClassName("t2");
        if (book != null){
            alert ("HI")

}else{
    alert("HIIII")
}
}
</script>
```

CSS

```
    table { 
  color: #333;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  /* Table reset stuff */
  border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; 
}

td, th {  border: 20 none; height: 30px; }

th {
  /* Gradient Background */
    background: linear-gradient(#333 0%,#444 100%);
    color: #FFF; font-weight: bold;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 30 0 30;
}

td { text-align: center; border: 7px solid white; padding: 0px;}

.t { background: #fff }
.t2 { background: #f00 }

/* First-child blank cells! */
tr td:first-child, tr th:first-child { 
    background: none; 
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 80px; 
}

/* Add border-radius to specific cells! */
tr:first-child th:nth-child(2) { 
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0; 
} 

tr:first-child th:last-child { 
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0; 
}
```

Comment: Okay i will do that! Sorry i am kind of a beginner.

Comment: `<style>` belongs in `<head>`, not between `<head>` and `<body>`

Comment: Will you prefer to use jQuery? Its very easy with it, and a bit complex with javascript

Comment: @GauravRai I don't mind using  Jquery if it will work here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the onclick of the button, you can try this..

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {

    var t2Cells = document.getElementsByClassName("t2");

    for(var i=0; i<t2Cells.length; i++){
    getStyle = t2Cells.item(i).currentStyle ? t2Cells.item(i).currentStyle : getComputedStyle(t2Cells.item(i));
    backgroundColor = getStyle.backgroundColor;
    if(backgroundColor == "rgb(255, 0, 0)"){
         console.log("true");
         alert('Coordinates are: '+t2Cells.item(i).cellIndex+'x'+t2Cells.item(i).parentNode.rowIndex);
    }      
    }
}
</script>
```

[image]

Sorry for the previous version, tested now !!

Comment: @Lchai Please check the edited JS function, tested in Chrome and it is working.

Comment: Yes, the edited js function solved this question! :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/lakami/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output

```
function Bookings(){

  // Get all .t2 cells
  var t2Cells = document.getElementsByClassName("t2");
  // Prepare coordinates Array
  var coordinates = [];

  // Loop all .t2 elements
  for(var i=0; i<t2Cells.length; i++){
    // Push gBCR Object into our Array
    coordinates.push( t2Cells[i].getBoundingClientRect() );
  }

  // Done
  console.log( coordinates ); // Open console to see the sizes and positions of .t2 cells

  // Use Examples:
  var alreadyBookedTot /* are red; total */ = coordinates.length;
  if( alreadyBookedTot>0 ){
      alert(coordinates.length +" are booked!"); // "N are booked!"
      // The first one:
      alert("First at X:"+ coordinates[0].left +" Y:"+ coordinates[0].top)

      // Or for loop `coordinates` Array here, and use indexes
      for(var n=0; n<alreadyBookedTot; n++){
          alert(coordinates[n].left+' '+coordinates[n].top)
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, what i meant is that i want to find out the position of the cell in the table.For example row 2 column 5 is colored red.